# Math beetween 2 selects in sql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm doing a simple task for a c# application and I thought about doing all the math in SQL instead.

I have 1 table called xx_MainOeuvre, and I perform 2 select on it. :

```
select xx_TypeMO, xx_pu from xx_MainOeuvre mo 
where mo.xx_TypeDuree != 1 and mo.xx_pu != 0 
and xx_sysParentId like 'CC1500107'
```

Gives me this :

```
xx_TypeMO   |   xx_pu   |
==========================
MOI         |     45    |
MOV         |     34    |
MOE         |     50    |
```

and

```
select xx_TypeMO, sum(xx_Duree) as TimeSpend
from xx_MainOeuvre
where xx_TypeDuree = 1 and xx_sysParentId like 'CC1500107'
group by xx_TypeMO
```

witch gives me this :

```
xx_TypeMO   |   TimeSpend   |
=============================
MOI         |     4         |
MOV         |     12        |
```

xx_pu is the unitPrice

I would like a result with the timeSpend * unitPrice.

Like this :

```
xx_TypeMO   |   RealPrice    |
==============================
MOI         |     180 (4*45) |
MOV         |     408 (12*34)|
```

Is it possible to do so ? Or should I stay with my C# method ?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: @Ravi I've added the expected output

Comment: personally i would collect all the data and do the calculations in C# because if you collect all the data you can perform other calculations elsewhere in the program

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a single, simpler query:

```
select xx_TypeMO,
       (sum(case when xx_TypeDuree = 1 then xx_Duree else 0 end) *
        sum(mo.xx_TypeDuree <> 1 and mo.xx_pu <> 0 )
       )
from xx_MainOeuvre
where xx_sysParentId like 'CC1500107'
group by xx_TypeMO
```

Comment: Thanks, I've modified it a little bit and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery for that. Something like this (I didn't test it though):

```
SELECT mo1.xx_TypeMO,
    mo1.xx_pu * mo2.timeSpend AS RealPrice
FROM xx_MainOeuvre mo1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT xx_TypeMO,
        SUM(xx_Duree) AS timeSpend
    FROM xx_MainOeuvre
    WHERE xx_TypeDuree = 1
    GROUP BY xx_TypeMO
) mo2 ON mo1.xx_TypeMO = mo2.xx_TypeMO
    AND mo1.xx_sysParentId = mo2.xx_sysParentId
WHERE mo1.xx_TypeDuree != 1 AND mo1.xx_pu != 0 
    AND xx_sysParentId = 'CC1500107'
```

Comment: Thanks, I've modified a little bit and works like a Charm.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the both answer (that I modified a little bit) I've got 2 working queries :

```
SELECT mo1.xx_TypeMO,
    xx_pu * timeSpend AS RealPrice FROM xx_MainOeuvre mo1 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT xx_TypeMO,
        SUM(xx_Duree) AS timeSpend
    FROM xx_MainOeuvre
    WHERE xx_TypeDuree = 1 and xx_sysParentId like 'CC1500107'
    GROUP BY xx_TypeMO ) mo2 ON mo1.xx_TypeMO = mo2.xx_TypeMO
    AND mo1.xx_sysParentId = xx_sysParentId WHERE mo1.xx_TypeDuree != 1 AND mo1.xx_pu != 0 
    AND xx_sysParentId = 'CC1500107'
```

and

```
    select xx_TypeMO, sum(case when xx_TypeDuree = 1 then xx_Duree else 0 end) * sum(mo.xx_pu)
from xx_MainOeuvre mo
where xx_sysParentId like 'CC1500107'
group by xx_TypeMO
```